# SQL query to get the count of documents in different tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:  Table1, Table2

`Table 1` will contain the data:

| student_id | Document_type | Document_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | PDF | 1 |
| 0002 | Excel | 2 |
| 0003 | word | 3 |
| 0004 | PDF | 1 |
| 0005 | Text | 4 |
| 0006 | CSV | 5 |

`Table 2` will contain the data:

| student_id | Document_type | Document_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | PDF | 1 |
| 0002 | Excel | 2 |
| 0003 | PDF | 3 |
| 0004 | PDF | 1 |
| 0007 | Text | 4 |
| 0003 | CSV | 5 |

Need to get the count of the documents based on id. For example, I only need to get document no1, document no 2, and document 3 counts based on the student id like below.

| student_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2 |
| 0002 | 2 |
| 0003 | 3 |
| 0004 | 2 |

actually in the output will be 2 columns one is id, and the second is count. The first column will be id and the next column will be count based on the document_no which we are giving in the query itself ( Table1,Table2).

Answer (score 2):

Use a union query and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT student_id FROM Table1 WHERE Document_no IN (1, 2, 3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT student_id FROM Table2 WHERE Document_no IN (1, 2, 3)
) t
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY student_id;
```